# Send me a email when my app service gets an Error 500 on Azure

Tags: azure, logic, azure-application-insights

Im trying to create an alert with Logic Apps on Azure, but I'm not doing well...

My scenario is: I have an app service running, and I want to automate the alerts to send me a email when this app service gets an error 500.

I created an Application Insight and its working good, and now I'm trying to integrate it with an Logic App script.

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Google azure monitor alerts and action groups.

Answer (score 2):

On my work we do that directly with application insights alerts:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log

[image]

Try it!!

Comment: Hey man! In the end, did you manage to make it work as you wanted?

Comment: Hey my friend, yes! I configured like you said using application insights alerts. But i`m still trying configure using logic apps. Thank you.

Comment: I've been looking at how to do it with a logic app. There it isn't any trigger for the application Insights so you will have to do it with and schedule and then run and Application Insights Action "Run analytics query", and with the output of this action see if you have to send and email or not. Shomething like this, but its gonna be more expensive in this way man!